# how to avoid dependency name-conflicts with global translation function _( ) in python?

Tags: localization, wxpython

I'm trying to internationalize / translate a python app that is implemented as a wx.App(). I have things working for the most part -- I see translations in the right places. But there's a show-stopper bug: crashing at hard-to-predict times with errors like:

```
Traceback: ...
    self.SetStatusText(_('text to be translated here'))
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

I suspect that one or more of the app's dependencies (there are quite a few) is clobbering the global translation function, _( ). One likely way would be doing so by using _ as the name of a dummy var when unpacking a tuple (which is fairly widespread practice). I made sure its not my app that is doing this, so I suspect its a dependency that is. Is there some way to "defend" against this, or otherwise deal with the issue?

I suspect this is a common situation, and so people have worked out how to handle it properly. Otherwise, I'll go with something like using a nonstandard name, such as _translate, instead of _. I think this would work, but be more verbose and a little harder to read., e.e.,

Answer (score 0):

From the above I can not see what is going wrong.

Don't have issues with I18N in my wxPython application I do use matplotlib and numpy in it (not extensive).

Can you give the full traceback and/or a small runnable sample which shows the problem.

BTW, have you seen this page in the wxPython Phoenix doc which gives some other references at the end.
wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/internationalization.html

Aha, if *Translate works then you run into the issue of Python stealing "*", you can workaround that by doing this:

Install a custom displayhook to keep Python from setting the global _ (underscore) to the value of the last evaluated expression.  If we don't do this, our mapping of _ to gettext can get overwritten. This is useful/needed in interactive debugging with PyShell.

you do this by defining in your App module:

```
def _displayHook(obj):
    """Custom display hook to prevent Python stealing '_'."""
    if obj is not None:
        print repr(obj)
```

and then in your wx.App.OnInit method do:

```
# work around for Python stealing "_"
sys.displayhook = _displayHook
```

Comment: Changing all instances of _() to _translate() has indeed cleared it up. But that's a work around, not a proper fix. Yes, I saw the linked doc info, thanks.